# Ĉu oni "spektas televidilon" aŭ oni "spektas televidon"?

Tags: word-choice

Kiu esprimo inter "spekti televidilon" kaj "spekti televidon" estas la plej ĝusta? Ĉu fakte ili ne signifas la saman aferon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Televidilo estas aparato; tio estas, la ekrano, anteno, ktp. Vi ja povas spekti ĝin, eĉ se ĝi estas malŝaltita! Sed televido estas, [laŭ PIV](http://vortaro.net/#televido):

> 1 Transdistanca vido.
>
> 2 Transsendo de spektaĵoj je granda distanco per elektromagnetaj ondoj: komerca, ŝtata, interŝtata televido; kolora televido; kabla televido (transsendo de televidaj programoj per kablo).

Laŭ ReVo ĝi signifas ankaŭ la elsendaĵoj mem (interalie), kaj tiel ĝi ofte uziĝas. Do, "spekti televidon" multe pli oftas, ĉar la elsendaĵoj estas multe pli interesaj ol la aparato! Se vi volas specifigi, ke vi parolas pri la movbildoj/sono kaj ne pri la aliaj signifoj de "televido", vi povas diri "televidaĵo" aŭ "televida programo".

Notu, ke estas ankaŭ verbo "televidi", kiu signifas "rigardi televidan programon".

Comment: <<Vi ja povas spekti ĝin, eĉ se ĝi estas malŝaltita!>> Ne, Kristan, vi ne povas. „spekti” laŭdifine estas aŭdi kaj rigardi samtempe. Oni ne povas aŭdi elŝaltitan televidilon!

Answer (score 6):

Oni spektas televidprogramon (aŭ televidon) per televidilo.

Oni ankaŭ simple povas televidi ion -- "ni televidis la futbalmatĉon" egalas al "ni spektis la futbalmatĉon per la televidilo".

Comment: Ho, vi respondis dum mi tajpis mian respondon! Pardonu...